# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline referencing the wrong image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

In my `application.css.scss` I reference an image like this:

```
body {
    background: #7d9ec4 url(asset-path('background.png', image)) no-repeat fixed bottom center;
}
```

It is located in `app/assets/images/background.png` and it works perfectly fine in dev.

I'm deploying to Heroku, so I need to precompile the assets. After I run `rake assets:precompile` the comiled files show up in `public/assets/` and  my background.png gets this filename: `background-876262e736e0b48500313d1a48005396.png`(no surprise, I know it's the fingerprint).

What baffles me is that the compiled `application-7665539658a117373a79cd8568f36315.css` tries to load `/assets/background-61d37b9fc285589fc0016694e6f8d134.png`, which clearly is the wrong fingerprint.

So I deleted all files from `public/assets/` and compiled again, added the new files to git (and removed the old ones), committed and pushed to Heroku - but no luck: the CSS still uses the wrong `background-xyz.png`.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: i think there was an issue in the Rails Github issue tracker about this.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2569

Comment: Oh no... Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Marian: If you put this in as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there was an issue in the Rails Github issue tracker about this:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2569